# Is there any way to perform MLE on a 1d gaussian mixture model comprised of two gaussians?

Tags: maximum-likelihood, gaussian-mixture-distribution

The MLE of the mean of a single gaussian distribution is the mean of the sample. But is there any way to do this when you have two gaussians such as in the figure attached? I know how to estimate the two means with a methods like least squares regression. But I am wondering could a MLE of this type of distribution exist? Is there a proof showing that is does not?[image]

Comment: Since the sum of two independent Gaussians is Gaussian, I suspect by "sum" you might have something else in mind, perhaps a mixture?  Please provide some details of what it means to "have two Gaussians" so that we can offer appropriate advice.

Comment: Here’s a vignette in Python using sklearn: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/mixture.html

Comment: There are a lot of threads about MLE of Gaussian mixture models here on CV: see https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=mixture+likelihood+gaussian.  Note especially the problem with "collapsing" one component onto a point.  They clearly answer your main question, though: you can apply MLE.